# How to check the status of another tickers moving average in a strategy back test

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am trying to include in a pinescript strategy a check to see if SPY 50 SMA is above the SPY 200 SMA that would cancel the trade if the 50 is below the 200. How would I go about doing that?

I have tried using a script generator but I am new to pinescript and still trying to figure things out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.